# MFC: How I can get wnd of check box button , in list ctrl with LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES style

Tags: c++, mfc

When I am creating mfc list ctrl with LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES stile and disabling this list , check boxes dont becoming gray , how can I get wnd of checkboxes or how can I fix this issue? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no HWNDs for the checkboxes, as they are not actual controls. They are implemented as state images on the list items instead.  So to do what you are looking for, you would have to assign your own `HIMAGELIST` to the list, then you can use whatever images you want (use `DrawFrameControl()` or `DrawThemeBackground()` to create bitmaps of standard checkbox images).  When you disable/enable the list, change the list item state indexes accordingly.